# Looping in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I would like to repeat the similar commands with replacing few variables in Robot framework. Could please suggest me  how to do it?

Here is the sample code:

```
variable1 = ['abc']
varaible2 = ['123','456']

|    | Run Keyword And Continue On Failure | testing | ${variable1} | ${variable2} | ${GetVal} | ${Check} |

variable3 = ['xyz']
varaible2 = ['678','789']

|    | Run Keyword And Continue On Failure | testing | ${variable3} | ${variable4} | ${GetVal} | ${Check} |
```

Comment: can `variable1` have more than one item? Do you want to loop over both `variable1` and `variable2` at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

Yes Robot framework supports for loops here is the example

```
:FOR    ${animal}    IN    cat    dog  
\    Log    ${animal}  
\    Log    2nd keyword  
Log    Outside loop
```

For More Examples Please go through this link

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops

Answer (score 2):

Robot framework provides a "for" loop with the special keyword `:FOR` (see [For Loops](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops) in the user guide)

```
| | :FOR | ${v2} | IN | @{variable2}
| | | Run keyword and continue on failure
| | | ... | testing | ${variable1} | ${v2} | ${GetVal} | ${Check}
```

Notice that the body of the loop has an extra level of indentation.

If you want to do nested loops you'll need to create a separate keyword for the nested loop. It very quickly becomes easier to write a single python keyword that does all of the looping and logic, as robot really isn't designed to be a general purpose programming language.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example which loops for a given number

```
 : FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE       200    
        \    Log To Console             ${INDEX}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are very good at explaining how to write a simple FOR loop in Robot Framework, so this is added clarity for your information.

First of all, the code to do as you're asking is as follows, assuming the various unknown variables are already defined elsewhere:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Do Your Test
    :FOR    ${INDEX}  IN RANGE    ${INCLUSIVE_STARTING_INDEX1}     ${EXCLUSIVE_ENDING_INDEX1}
    \   Run Keyword and Continue On Failure     testing    ${variable1}    ${variable2}    ${GetVal}   ${Check}
    :FOR    ${INDEX}  IN RANGE    ${INCLUSIVE_STARTING_INDEX2}     ${EXCLUSIVE_ENDING_INDEX2}
    \   Run Keyword and Continue On Failure     testing    ${variable3}    ${variable4}    ${GetVal}   ${Check}
```

Second, I need to clarify that FOR Loops in Robot Framework are **NOT** Keywords. They're distinctively separate entities at the most basic level in the language. I learned this by spending hours delving into the code, trying to figure out how it might be possible to code a nestable For loop. To save you the effort of trying, it isn't without coding your own customized keyword in Python.

Also, I should specify that I'm taking the liberty of assuming that you made a few typos in your question, and that your personalized keyword "testing" that you wrote somewhere else accepts a list object as its second input variable. If that is incorrect, let me know and I'll give you a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one loop you can use

```
:FOR    ${iTemp}    IN    @{listOfStudents}
 \    Log    ${iTemp}  
 \    Log    GO_ON.
```

but you can't make loop inside loop 
for that you should use keyword for that like below

```
First Loop
   :FOR    ${i}    IN    @{listOfStudents}
   \    Log    ${i}  
   \    Log    OutSide Loop

Outside Loop
   :FOR    ${j}    IN    @{ListOfSubject}  
   \    Log    ${j}  
   \    Log    new Kewords.
```

Thats the way you can use loops in Robot Framework

Thasnks

Answer (score 0):

```
For loop syntax was enhanced in Robot Framework 3.1. New syntax is as follows:

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    FOR    ${animal}    IN    cat    dog
        Log    ${animal}
        Log    2nd keyword
    END
    Log    Outside loop

Second Example
    FOR    ${var}    IN    one    two    ${3}    four    ${five}
    ...    kuusi    7    eight    nine    ${last}
        Log    ${var}
    END
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: please come with discribtion, not only code answer